# Real-time chat with Django REST backend and iOS

Tags: ios, django, swift, sockets, django-rest-framework

I'm currently developing an iOS app with a custom Django REST backend. Using REST calls I can create/login users and make blog entries. I wanted to implement a chat feature so that my users could send private real time messages to each other.

I have no experience with web sockets and how they work. I wanted to know what is the best way to go about developing the chat feature.

Current set-up:
- iOS app using swift 3
- Django 1.10 for server

Comment: Django Channels if you wanna implement froper websockets. https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: You need to use [django-channels](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=django+channels&oq=django+channels+&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61j69i60l2j0l2.4954j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for backend and for frontend [socket.io for ios](http://socket.io/blog/socket-io-on-ios/). take a look at django-channels application [blog](https://blog.heroku.com/in_deep_with_django_channels_the_future_of_real_time_apps_in_django) by **jacob-kaplan-moss**.